# Selenium WebDriver Exceptions - "element not interact-able"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select elements from a drop down box, which loads options once clicked. I can get to the element but not interact with it. The error is NOT due to the page not fully loading as most related questions are.

I've tried selecting element by Id, Xpath, and using the js to make the element not hidden, none have worked so far. the latest i've tried was to send the keys.down to activate the list... still get the "not interactable" error.

Web page with selector--

```
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="css-1wy0on6 av__indicators">
                                        <span class="css-bgvzuu-indicatorSeparator av__indicator-separator">
                                        </span>
                                        <div aria-hidden="true" class="css-1u02eyf-indicatorContainer av__indicator av__dropdown-indicator">
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="css-19bqh2r" focusable="false" height="20" viewbox="0 0 20 20" width="20">
                                                <path d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z">
                                                </path>
                                            </svg>
                                            <span class="sr-only">
                                                Toggle Select Options
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input name="organization" type="hidden" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" disabled="" type="submit">
                            Continue
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Some Python code used so far--

```
 elem = driver.find_element_by_name("organization")
js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; 
arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';"

 driver.execute_script(js, elem)


 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 elem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

 ###not interactable Error
```

I would expect the item to allow me to select or activate the options list at the least. I have been successful in  lists, but not this new  type.

Comment: post url link to the webpage

Comment: The web page requires a login by a medical provider, so it may not help completely.  https://apps.availity.com/public/apps/home/#!/loadApp?appUrl=%2Fweb%2Fui-generator%2Fui-app%2F%3FcacheBust%3D1559934816%23%2Fclaim-management-landing

Answer (score 0):

The `INPUT` you are trying to interact with is of `type="hidden"` so it won't be visible and can't be interacted with using Selenium. My guess is that there's a dropdown that isn't a `SELECT` that is displayed, the user makes a selection, and then code pushes that value into the hidden `INPUT`. Just ignore the hidden `INPUT` and interact with the page as a user would by clicking the dropdown, then clicking your selection. The rest should take care of itself.

We can't make more recommendations on locators, etc. without more of the HTML of the page since you stated that the site is behind an account.

Comment: Thanks, that was a last resort for me to do using mouse/keyboard commands. Although, I find it much cleaner to send the actual commands through the webdriver. Best I have been able to do so far is to capture the hidden element once the keyboard tabs to it, but not extract what element is actually allowing me to control it. 

keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
element2 = driver.switch_to.active_element

element2.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
 this works, but I cannot extract what the xpath or otherwise is for element2 and all the attributes come up blank using element.get_attribute('value')